# Ruby string escaping, for serialization (string dumping and loading)

Tags: ruby, serialization, escaping, deserialization

I have a string which I would like to *serialize* and *deserialize*.  This one for instance:

```
"hello, world"
```

Now, if I find-and-replace (**dump** step) every `world` sub-string by `o`, this string become:

```
"hello, o"
```

But, if I try to find-and-replace again in the other way from `o` to `world` (**load** step), this string become:

```
"hellworld, world"
```

...which is not the same as the first string.  Is there a easy way to handle this, escaping chars, with Ruby 1.9.2?

Thank you!

**EDIT**:

In other words, I would be able to:

1. Replace a parameter (for example "`world`") in a text by a value (for example "`o`").
2. Replace any values ("`o`", according to the example) by the parameter ("`world`", according to the example)

So I would like to be able to do so (with something like `dump()` and `load()` methods):

```
string = "Hello world, Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 is out! Yay!"
serialized_string = dump(string)
    # => "Hell\o o, Ruby \on Rails 3.1.0 is \out! Yay!"

load(serialized_string).should == string # => true
```

Thanks for any idea :)

Comment: Why are you using `"o"`, a string which is likely to be elsewhere in the original article?

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: Because it's a plaintext.  I can only parse it.  I'm trying to get a thin string serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why are you doing this?
This has not much to do with ruby, but with regular expressions.

Anyway, wouldn't it be easier to store the original string, so that you can restore it?

Alternatively, if you only want to match the last `o`, try to use the pattern `o$`.

But I really think you should provide more info about your actual use-case.

Comment: I would like to be able to do this in order to dump and load any string. I think the key is to escape the returned string after each edition.

Comment: @Puru, please update your question with specifics about how you'd like to dump and load any string, presumably with examples of what you'd like to stay intact when round-tripped. There are several libraries, some part of the standard library, that do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gsub` with a regular expression that would work.

```
"hello, o".gsub /o$/, world
```

I believe that will do what you want.

**EDIT**

If you know that the word will always be surrounded with white space, beginning, or end of string you could use something like:

```
o = "whatever you want"
world = "the very long article you mentioned"
"an even longer article".gsub /^#{o}&|^#{o}\s|\s#{o}\s|\s#{o}&/, world
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a more generic method?  My string was just an example.  This could be an article...

Comment: no, but I just updated my question. Now it's more clear, I think.